# Different ways to create a 5 different digit integer

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways to create a five digit integer such that all of the digits are different is $9 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 = 27216$. However, if I select the numbers from the ones digits first, I get $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$. I can't quite get what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone explain and give me the correct working for choosing numbers starting from the ones digit?

Comment: It's hard to start with ones place, because of the $0$.  If the $0$ gets used in any of the first four selections, then you are right about there being $6$ choices for the leading digit.  If it does not get used, then there are only $5$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to split into two cases, according to whether or not the $0$ appears in the least $4$ slots.

Case I:  the $0$ does appear.  There are $4$ ways to place the $0$, then $9\times8\times 7\times 6$ ways to populate the other slots.  Thus $$ 4\times 9\times 8\times 7\times 6=\boxed{12096}$$

Case II:  the $0$ does not appear.  Then you just have nine digits to work with, with no constraints.  Thus $$9\times8\times 7\times 6\times 5=\boxed {15120}$$

Combining these we get $$12096+15120=\fbox {27216}$$  matching the other (easier) method.

Answer (score 4):

There are $10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6=30\,240$  strings  having $5$ different digits. One tenth of these strings begin with a $0$, which is forbidden. The number of admissible strings therefore is $27\,216$.